# monacaでビルドしたアプリに(*)がつく

Tags: monaca

monacaでデバッグビルドしたapkをインストールすると『アプリ名(*)』のようになってしますのですが、こちら(*)を無くす方法はございますでしょうか？

Comment: Myaku さん
ありがとうございました。
解決しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

デバッグビルドでははずすことはできません。
リリースビルドでビルドしましょう。
Androidであればリリースビルドを行ってもインストールは出来ます。